# Setting subview's width equal to window width on launch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, window, nswindow

I'm struggling getting a subview (which is acting as a custom toolbar [I need a `NSView` rather than an `NSToolbar`]) centred within an `INAppStoreWindow`..

The subview is being added correctly, and stretches correctly *only if the window is exactly the same width as the custom view that I've created in IB*.

If the window opens wider than the custom view, it does not stretch properly. The window seems to open in exactly the same state as I left it (in Lion), which therefore means I have to set the width of the custom view to the restored window width  on launch.

It's also important that the buttons etc I have placed in the centre of the view in the nib remain centred...

How do I do this?

Edit: to make this clear, **how do I get a restored window's width? I have set it to 480 in the nib file but if I resize the window, quit then restart the app, `window.frame.size.width` still returns 480, not the width I quit with..**

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are not creating the `NSWindow` in interface builder, you can override `-[NSView viewDidMoveToWindow]` or `-[NSView viewWillMoveToWindow]` to set the width, there are also `viewDidMoveToView` equivalents which may make more sense since you view gets added to the `NSWindows` contentView, there is also `awakeFRomNib` which you can override which may b he better choice if you only have to worry about the issue once when you vie loads from the Nib file.

Comment: No, the NSWindow is created in IB..

I also don't know how to get the width of the window..

Comment: What you want is the width it the window content view with -[NSWindow contentView] you can then get the content views bounds with -[NSView bounds], if the custom view is being added to the window in interface builder I am not sure why setting the autoresizing controls in interface builder is not working.

Comment: Actually instead of getting the windows contentView you are probable bettwe of using -[NSView superview] in the [NSView viewDidMoveToSuperview], which means you code will work when added to any super view including the windows contentView,